# Arrayformula to distribute ramp-up cost on other projects

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to solve this with an ARRAYFORMULA, but I'm sort of stuck, so I was hoping I could get some help here. So, I have this project calculation sheet, containing multiple customers and multiple projects. We have Ramp-up costs ("ToAllocate=TRUE", per customer) we need to distribute to other projects ("Carrier=TRUE", per customer). The Ramp-up costs (Cost per hour * Hours) need to be distributed to "Carrier" projects proportional to number of project hours / total of carrier hours. I need to come up with the arrayformula so I would have the column M filled in:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OsWX80jvKgQAYuHi56ULBPm43GrZrnt7bvwtH5dy-ZM/edit?usp=sharing
(columns J, K and L are helper columns so i wouldn't put everything in M column)

Comment: so you say you dont need JKL columns?

Comment: I need the results in M column. But instead of putting everything into 1 cell, I thought it would be easier to understand the steps if I split the formula into multiple steps. So the 3 columns are steps for achieving the result in M. But I need to have the calculation in array formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete everything in **J2:M** range

paste this formula into **J2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D=TRUE; {
       VLOOKUP(A2:A; QUERY(A:H; "select A,sum(H) where C=TRUE group by A"; 0); 2; 0)\
  F2:F/VLOOKUP(A2:A; QUERY(A:H; "select A,sum(F) where D=TRUE group by A"; 0); 2; 0)\
       VLOOKUP(A2:A; QUERY(A:H; "select A,sum(H) where C=TRUE group by A"; 0); 2; 0)*
 (F2:F/VLOOKUP(A2:A; QUERY(A:H; "select A,sum(F) where D=TRUE group by A"; 0); 2; 0))\
  I2:I+VLOOKUP(A2:A; QUERY(A:H; "select A,sum(H) where C=TRUE group by A"; 0); 2; 0)*
 (F2:F/VLOOKUP(A2:A; QUERY(A:H; "select A,sum(F) where D=TRUE group by A"; 0); 2; 0))}; ))
```

[image: 0]